# Has Promotion and Relegation been used in North American Major Leagues

Tags: history, promotions, relegations, major-leagues

There are 4 major sports leagues in North America: NFL, MLB, NBA, and NHL. The teams, also known as the franchises, in the league don't change. The only exceptions are when a team moves to a different city (still the same franchise) and when the league expands by adding more teams.

This is very different to European football leagues where promotion and relegation is practiced. A small number of teams that finish last in a season are relegated to the lower league, and the top teams of the lower league are promoted to replace them.

Has there been a time where the North American major leagues practiced promotion and relegation?

Comment: @Nij I removed the "if not, why north american leagues don't do promote and relegation". This question is different than the one marked as a duplicate of. Here I'm asking for any occurrences of promote and relegation in major north american sport in the past, not the reason.

Comment: I agree with Nij's proposed dupe, as it does answer your question.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I disagree. When closing a question as dup, the description below it reads: "The question has been asked before and already has an answer". Note that my question asks for the history/occurrences of Promotion and Relegation (P&R) where as the other is asking why it doesn't exist in North America (NA). I've read all answers to that question, non of those discuss if P&R has been used in the 4 major leagues of NA. btw even if one of the answers of the that question answered mine, since the other question doesn't have an accepted answer I find it unreasonable to mark this question as dup

Comment: If you read the question...

Comment: I don't understand your comment